# Can the icon and text be removed from a PWA splash screen?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

In other words, can a PWA splash screen just be a solid custom color?

In my PWA, the splash screen occurs so quickly, there's not enough time for a user to register what they're seeing. It could be perceived as an error/problem or just simply sloppy design.

For reference, the site is online, I'm using wireless (LTE) on my phone, and service worker cache disabled. I haven't yet tried it with the service worker cache enabled, but I assume the splash will disappear even faster!

For a PWA splash screen, I'd rather just have a custom solid color (which would match my website background).

Comment: Based on https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen this doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/custom-splash-screen, a splash screen must have:

1. A `name` property in the manifest
2. A `background_color` in the manifest
3. Icons set with one at least 512px by 512px
4. The Icon being PNG format

This does not leave the option to leave out any of the previous settings.

However, you can set the icon to be a solid color with the same color as the background. This should make it so that the user cannot see any icon.

Answer (score 2):

Use an icon that is the same color as your splash screen background color. The icon will then not be visual different from the rest of the splash screen.